# Xampp returns "Protocol POST http44 not supported or disabled in libcurl "

Tags: php, linux, curl, libcurl

I have read all Ask pages here and my question is not duplicate because i tried all of the solutions they said.

- I am trying to run my code in local server.
- My Xampp software has only one php.ini file that located in : "C:\xampp\php\php.ini"
- This line was active in php.ini already : "extension=php_curl.dll;"
- The library file exist here : "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll"

But when i run this code :

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('POST https://sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'api_user=xxxxx&api_key=xxxxxx&to=xxxxxx@yahoo.com&toname=Alex&subject=testing&html=<div style="background-color:red;">Test email</div>
&from=xxxxx@gmail.com');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
echo  curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
?>
```

I just receive this error :

```
Protocol POST https not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Have you tried re-install xampp?

Comment: try with a different URL and also restart `Apache`  from xampp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `curl_init()` must be a URL. The word `POST` has no business being in there; remove it.

Comment: Yes you right , i have copied the command line code into php curl